# Prestashop, always show product availability

Tags: php, prestashop, product

I set up my store to allow order also for products that quantity is <=0.
So, in Product configuration setted to show product quantities in the product page and allowed orders for out of stock products. Maybe I have a problem with my template but I can see availability of products only when are >0. I need to always show availability(2 available, 0 available, -2 available).

This is my FO product page(this size not available):
[FO product, size not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySThf.png)

This is my FO product page(size available):
[FO product, size available][3]

If I set in BO to not allow orders for out of stock products I can see the text that I want to see also if I allow orders for out of stock products.

As you can see, only when the product is >0 the availability is shown. I just want to ALWAYS show availability because I need to allow orders for out of stock products.

I think that I need to edit this part of product.tpl

```
{if ($display_qties == 1 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && $product->available_for_order)}
<!-- number of item in stock -->
<p id="pQuantityAvailable"{if $product->quantity <= 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
<span id="quantityAvailable">{$product->quantity|intval}</span>
<span {if $product->quantity > 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxt">{l s='Item'}</span>
<span {if $product->quantity == 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxtMultiple">{l s='Items'}</span>
</p>
{/if}
{if $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT}
<!-- availability -->
<p id="availability_statut"{if ($product->quantity <= 0 && !$product->available_later && $allow_oosp) || ($product->quantity > 0 && !$product->available_now) || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE}{/if}>
{*<span id="availability_label">{l s='Availability:'}</span>*}
<span id="availability_value"{if $product->quantity <= 0 && !$allow_oosp} class="warning_inline"{/if}>{if $product->quantity <= 0}{if $allow_oosp}{$product->available_later}{else}{l s='This product is no longer in stock'}{/if}{else}{$product->available_now}{/if}</span>
</p>
{hook h="displayProductDeliveryTime" product=$product}
<p class="warning_inline" id="last_quantities"{if ($product->quantity > $last_qties || $product->quantity <= 0) || $allow_oosp || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE}{/if} >{l s='Warning: Last items in stock!'}</p>
{/if}
<p id="availability_date"{if ($product->quantity > 0) || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE || !isset($product->available_date) || $product->available_date < $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d'}{/if}>
<span id="availability_date_label">{l s='Availability date:'}</span>
<span id="availability_date_value">{dateFormat date=$product->available_date full=false}</span>
</p>
<!-- Out of stock hook -->
<div id="oosHook"{if $product->quantity > 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
{$HOOK_PRODUCT_OOS}
</div>
```

tried different things removing some of

```
style="display: none;"
```

with no success.

I will appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If none of this code is displayed some of the `if` conditions are `false`:

```
{if ($display_qties == 1 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && $product->available_for_order)}
```

I assume that your shop is not in catalog mode so I think if could be the `available_for_order` field from product edit screen.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

tried to change the code of the first post to:

```
{if ($display_qties == 1 OR $product->quantity <= $last_qties && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && $product->available_for_order)}
            <!-- number of item in stock -->
            <p id="pQuantityAvailable"{if $product->quantity <= 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                <span id="quantityAvailable">{$product->quantity|intval}</span>
                <span {if $product->quantity > 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxt">{l s='Item'}</span>
                <span {if $product->quantity == 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxtMultiple">{l s='Items'}</span>
            </p>
        {/if}
        {if $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT}
            <!-- availability -->
            <p id="availability_statut"{if ($product->quantity <= 0 && !$product->available_later && $allow_oosp) OR ($product->quantity > 0 OR !$product->available_now) OR !$product->available_for_order OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                {<span id="availability_label">{l s='Availability:'}</span>}
                <span id="availability_value"{if $product->quantity <= 0} class="warning_inline"{/if}>{if $product->quantity <= 0}{if $allow_oosp}{$product->available_later}{else}{l s='This product is no longer in stock'}{/if}{else}{$product->available_now}{/if}</span>
            </p>
            {hook h="displayProductDeliveryTime" product=$product}
            <p class="warning_inline" id="last_quantities"{if ($product->quantity > $last_qties || $product->quantity <= 0) || $allow_oosp || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} {/if} >{l s='Warning: Last items in stock!'}</p>
        {/if}
        <p id="availability_date"{if ($product->quantity > 0) || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE || !isset($product->available_date) || $product->available_date < $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d'} {/if}>
            <span id="availability_date_label">{l s='Availability date:'}</span>
            <span id="availability_date_value">{dateFormat date=$product->available_date full=false}</span>
        </p>
        <!-- Out of stock hook -->
        <div id="oosHook"{if $product->quantity > 0}{/if}>
            {$HOOK_PRODUCT_OOS}
        </div>
```

So the problem is that it works perfectly when the product or a combination is available because I can see, for example, "2 Item available" but the problem still there when a product or a combination is not available. Nothing appear when the product is not available, in the code I can see that it would appear "This product is no longer in stock" but I can't see it...
I don't know why. Only the text in the span tags are shown, never the rest.